# Using custom container with functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component, victory-charts

I have defined a custom container:

```
const CombinedContainer = createContainer("selection", "voronoi");

const selectionStyle = {
  fill: "transparent",
  fillOpacity: 0.5,
  stroke: "red",
  strokeWidth: 1
}

type Props = {}

const ChartContainer = (props: Props) => (
  <CombinedContainer
    // @ts-ignore
    cursorDimension="x"
    selectionDimension="x"
    selectionStyle={selectionStyle}
    labels={({datum}) => `${datum.x}, ${datum.y.toFixed(2)} ${datum.volume}`}
  />
)

export default ChartContainer;
```

and using it like this:

```
<VictoryChart
  width={width}
  padding={padding}
  minDomain={{ y: 70 }}
  maxDomain={{ y: dataSet.maxDomain }}
  containerComponent={<ChartContainer />}
>
  ...
</VictoryChart>
```

but this doesn't render anything unless I use it like a normal function:

```
<VictoryChart
  width={width}
  padding={padding}
  minDomain={{ y: 70 }}
  maxDomain={{ y: dataSet.maxDomain }}
  containerComponent={ChartContainer({})}
>
  ...
</VictoryChart>
```

I have previously defined similar function components and used them without any problems but I can't see what am I doing wrong here. Can anyone help me?

Why `<ChartContainer />` doesn't work but `ChartContainer()` does?

`createContainer` function is defined as:

```
export type ContainerType =
  | "brush"
  | "cursor"
  | "selection"
  | "voronoi"
  | "zoom";
export function createContainer<V, W>(
  c1: ContainerType,
  c2: ContainerType
): React.ComponentType<V & W>;
```

Here is the sample project to test it:

https://github.com/olcayertas/victory-functional-container-componenet

Comment: What does `createContainer` function return?

Comment: It returns a component type, I have updated the question with the definition.

Comment: Could you setup minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @AlekseyL. I have added the project link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `ChartContainer` doesn't pass received props (and doesn't [render the children](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/blob/main/packages/victory-chart/src/victory-chart.js#L187)).

So just `{...props}` on `CombinedContainer`:

```
const ChartContainer = (props: Props) => (
  <CombinedContainer
    // @ts-ignore
    cursorDimension="x"
    selectionDimension="x"
    selectionStyle={selectionStyle}
    // @ts-ignore
    labels={({ datum }) =>
      `Date: ${datum.date}\nPrice: $${datum.close.toFixed(2)}\nVolume: ${
        datum.volume
      }`
    }
    {...props}
  />
);
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-austin-lzftu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: this is only fixing the rendering problem but the chart is still not working correctly: Labels are not showing and selection is not working. Very interesting,  i will ask this on Victory GitHub.

Comment: Apparently using functional components is not possible right now: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/1758